# Transfer files in and out of HDFS from Windows

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I need a way to transfer files in and out of HDFS from a node which is not a part of cluster.
Is a UI, with a browse button present to do that?
I am using a Windows machine from where I need to do a transfer to the HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

I think hoop can help you.
https://github.com/cloudera/hoop

> Hoop, Hadoop HDFS over HTTP
>
> Hoop is a server that provides a REST HTTP gateway to HDFS with full
>   read & write capabilities.
>
> Hoop is distributed under Apache License 2.0.
>
> Hoop has been contributed to Apache Hadoop and it is available as part
>   of Hadoop 0.23.x releases.

Comment: Cant I use pscp or psftp for the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you have network access (network, dns, firewall) to the cluster nodes from your windows machine, then you can use the [Eclipse Hadoop plugin](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipsePlugIn) to view and interact with HDFS (but again, it does require that you have the ability to contact the data nodes in the cluster).

Comment: Thanks. But I guess I need to create a jar first for the hadoop plugin, as hadoop now does not provide a jar by itself which it previously used to provide in /hadoop/contib/eclipse .

Also Can I use pscp or psftp for the purpose of transfer? Transfer to hdfs directly using either pscp or psftp?

Comment: No, there is no pscp or psftp interface - i guess you could pscp the file to a node inside the cluster (or one that has network access to the cluster nodes, and has hadoop installed / configure), and then follow up with an `ssh host hadoop fs -put file file`, but you'd need a ssh client that supports that style of syntax.

Comment: Thanks. The eclipse plugin would help me to directly transfer files in and out of HDFS? The eclipse would be in a machine which is not a part of cluster.

Comment: Yes is can be running on a machine not part of the cluster, but again i must stress, it must be able to communicate with the name node, and the data nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use HadoopDrive shell extension: http://hadoopdrive.effisoft.eu